# How do I use a parameter within BI Publisher to update the table name I am querying in an Oracle Data set

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

I am trying to create a BI Publisher data model which runs the Oracle query below -

```
SELECT * 
FROM audit_YYYYMM
```

(this should be the `YYYYMM` of the current date)

1. How do I setup a parameter default value within the datamodel to grab the `YYYYMM` from the `SYSDATE`?
2. How do I append this parameter within the data set SQL Query? 
   I tried `SELECT * FROM audit_:Month_YYYYMM`

   (where I had a string parameter called `Month_YYYMM`)

This did not work.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are trying to accomplish with each question? Why are you trying to change the table name with a parameter?

Comment: I think a better solution to solve your goal would be to use one table, and add a column called "audit_date" then select off that.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use something like EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE. And you may have to make a separate PL/SQL package to launch rather than use the built in data definition stuff.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm